# Grouping by category and sub category to produce a list in HTML from XML data

Tags: xml, xslt, xls, muenchian-grouping

I have some xml data that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="course-catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <course>
        <category>Category 1</category>
        <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
        <name>test name 1</name>
        <instructor>fred derp</instructor>
        <date>July 1</date>
        <url>http://foo.com</url>
    </course>

<course>
    <category>Category 1</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 2</subcategory>
    <name>test name 2</name>
    <instructor>john bravo</instructor>
    <date>March 19, 2008</date>
    <url>www.foorl.com/foo.html</url>
</course>

<course>
    <category>Category 2</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
    <name>test name 3</name>
    <instructor>Jack Nicholson</instructor>
    <date>July 2</date>
    <url>test.html</url>
</course>

<course>
    <category>Category 2</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
    <name>test name 4</name>
    <instructor>Jim Carrey</instructor>
    <date>July 21</date>
    <url>test3.html</url>
</course>




</catalog>
```

I want it to group by category and sub category (just using H1 H2 tags for the categories and sub categories, and the rest of the course data below that).

Using the xml data I provided, it should produce:

```
Category 1
  Sub 1
   test name 1, fred derp, July 1

  Sub 2
   test name 2, john bravo, March 19, 2008

Category 2
  Sub 1
....
...
```

So it should have a group and a sub group using xsl. It doesn't have to be in tables or anything, just a regular html list.

I tried using examples from this site already and can't find anything that works to what I need to do. I also tried W3 schools and it just shows an example using CDs and there is no grouping at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried that's not working? Can you update the question with your course_catalog.xsl?

Comment: I used xsl:for-each-group but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Having tagged this "Muenchian-grouping", I am assuming you need a solution in XSLT 1.0.  Grouping solutions are always easier in XSLT 2.0.

For multi-level grouping in XSLT 1.0 I prefer using the variable-based grouping method rather than the Muenchian key-based grouping method, acknowledging that it may be slower to execute but easier to understand the coding.

```
t:\ftemp>type armando.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="course-catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <course>
        <category>Category 1</category>
        <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
        <name>test name 1</name>
        <instructor>fred derp</instructor>
        <date>July 1</date>
        <url>http://foo.com</url>
    </course>

<course>
    <category>Category 1</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 2</subcategory>
    <name>test name 2</name>
    <instructor>john bravo</instructor>
    <date>March 19, 2008</date>
    <url>www.foorl.com/foo.html</url>
</course>

<course>
    <category>Category 2</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
    <name>test name 3</name>
    <instructor>Jack Nicholson</instructor>
    <date>July 2</date>
    <url>test.html</url>
</course>

<course>
    <category>Category 2</category>
    <subcategory>Sub 1</subcategory>
    <name>test name 4</name>
    <instructor>Jim Carrey</instructor>
    <date>July 21</date>
    <url>test3.html</url>
</course>

</catalog>
t:\ftemp>call xslta armando.xml armando.txt 
Producing armando.txt...

t:\ftemp>type armando.txt 

Category 1
  Sub 1
   test name 1, fred derp, July 1
  Sub 2
   test name 2, john bravo, March 19, 2008

Category 2
  Sub 1
   test name 3, Jack Nicholson, July 2
   test name 4, Jim Carrey, July 21

t:\ftemp>type course-catalog.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <xsl:variable name="categories" select="course"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                  generate-id($categories[category=current()/category][1])">
      <xsl:variable name="subs"
                    select="$categories[category=current()/category]"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$subs">
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                      generate-id($subs[subcategory=current()/subcategory][1])">
          <xsl:text>&#xa;  </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="subcategory"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$subs[subcategory=current()/subcategory]">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,', ',instructor,', ',date)"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```